# Compare 2 Arrays

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am comparing two Arrays in VBA for Excel 2010. Here is my sample code:

```
Dim vArray1 As Variant
Dim vArray2 As Variant

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set myTable = wb1.Worksheets(3).ListObjects("Table3")

vArray1 = myTable.DataBodyRange
vArray2 = wb1.Worksheets(2).Range("B1:B" & lRow1).Value

k = 1

For i = LBound(vArray1) To UBound(vArray1)
   For j = LBound(vArray2) To UBound(vArray2)
      If vArray1(i, 1) = vArray2(j, 1) Then
         ' Do nothing
      Else
         vArray3(k, 1) = vArray1(i, 1)
         k = k + 1
      End If
   Next
Next
```

I want to do a comparison of Column 1 in Table 3 with the range stored in vArray2.

Any value that is present in vArray1 but not present in vArray2 needs to be stored in vArray3. Unfortunately, I am cannot get this done. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Edit1:** I've re-written your loop a bit which is the cause of the problem I think. *Ubound* and *Lbound* assumes the first dimension if it is not supplied. So the way you do it and below should return the correct upper and lower bounds. But of course, it is better to be explicit when you're dealing with 2D arrays. Also *vArray3* should be *Dimensioned*. I didn't see it in your code. Also added a *Boolean* variable.

```
ReDim vArray3 (1 to 10, 1 to 2) '~~> change to suit
Dim dup As Boolean: k = 1
For i = LBound(vArray1, 1) To UBound(vArray1, 1) '~~> specify dimension
    dup = False
    For j = LBound(vArray2, 1) To UBound(vArray2, 1) '~~> specify dimension
        If vArray1(i, 1) = vArray2(j, 1) Then
            dup = True: Exit For
        End If
    Next j
    If Not dup Then '~~> transfer if not duplicate
        vArray3(k, 1) = vArray1(i, 1)
        k = k + 1
    End If
Next I
```

Or you can use match like this:

```
'~~> Use 1D array instead by using Transpose
vArray2 = Application.Transpose(wb1.Worksheets(2).Range("B1:B" & lRow1))
For i = LBound(vArray1, 1) To UBound(vArray1, 1) '~~> specify dimension
    If IsError(Application.Match(vArray1(i, 1), vArray2, 0)) Then
        vArray3(k, 1) = vArray1(i, 1)
        k = k + 1
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is checking for equality between two arrays, varArray1 and varArray2. The Join function is used to concatenate the elements of each array into a single string separated by commas.

Then, the two resulting strings are compared using the "=" operator to check if they are identical.

If they are, the variable IsEqual is set to True, indicating that the arrays are equal. If they are not equal, the code does not modify the value of IsEqual, so it remains False (or whatever value it had previously).

```
If (Join(varArray1, ",") = Join(varArray2, ",")) Then
    IsEqual = True
End If
```

Comment: Please add a description about your code. Not just only code!